# how to catch the value in between <a></a> in web scraping / regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, web-scraping

I want to get the value of that anchor tag it means I want that 1,947 from another website. What is the Regex?

```
<a onclick="ClearInfoAndDataTable();" href="/subdomains/all/all/1/ahrefs_rank_desc?target=www.homeocare.in">1,947</a>
```

I am using this code but not getting the values

```
   MatchCollection AltTag = Regex.Matches(myResponse, @"(?s)(?<=<a\s[^<]*?>)(.*?)(?=</a>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this Regex and Linq(this will give you an array of all the anchors):

```
var anchors = Regex.Matches(s, @"<a [^>]*>(.*?)</a>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```

or use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: im getting some anchor links .like 
<a href="/api"> Ahrefs API</a>
but not getting this link  values

<a onclick="ClearInfoAndDataTable();" href="/subdomains/all/all/1/ahrefs_rank_desc?target=www.homeocare.in">1,947</a>
@zaki